# How to retrieve field names in jaydata

Tags: jaydata, dynamic-tables

I have a simple database in Jaydata:

```
$data.Entity.extend("Person", {
Name: { type: String, required: true},
LastName: {type: String, required: true},
DepartmentId: {type: int}
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("PersonDatabase", {
People : { type : $data.EntitySet, elementType : Person}
});

var Database1= new PersonDatabase("MyDatabase");
```

But suppose I don't know the fields of the database I have. Assume I only know the variable **Database1** so I need to make a loop which returns column names(fields of "Person"). How can I make that so I can make a dynamic table which can show whatever simple database(#x columns, #y rows) data I will have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type in hand for example the Person class, call `type.getFieldNames()` for and array of public mapped field names (technical fields are not visible). To access each and every field with full metadata consult `type.memberDefinitions` or `type.memberDefinitions.toArray()`

The http://admin.jaystack.net site is build with fully generic table routines powered by knockout: check out admin.jaystack.net for an example (you need to register for a free account to access the admin site)